# How to disable the dashed contour for TabItem?

Tags: .net, wpf, focus, tabcontrol, tabitem

When a `TabItem` has focus it shows an inner dashed countour. How to make it transparent or to disabling it to get focus at all?

Comment: have you changed the header template as I dont think is does this as standard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about the FocusVisualStyle you can remove it by adding the following to your TabControl

```
<TabControl ...>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <!-- ... -->
</TabControl>
```

**Update**

To make sure we're talking about the same thing

Selected with FocusVisualStyle (dashed countour)
[image]

Selected without FocusVisualStyle. This is the look you'll get when the TabItem has focused (set by keyboard) and FocusVisualStyle is set to null
[image]

Comment: Interesting, but suprisingly I didn't get my expected result using this

Comment: I see, I was talking about a dashed contour in the tab body, not in the header.

Comment: @XMLforDummies: How does the body of your Tab Items look? Do you have a StackPanel, UserControl? Do disable focus you can set Focusable="False"